# How does the stack work for the item "Device"?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Relevant card text:

> You may discard this card to add 3 dice to your attack roll, but you may only use that attack to steal something.

How would this work in terms of the stack - for declaring attack and attack intention?

Is it legitimate to roll dice with the intention of making a regular attack, to see that the pip total is lower than desired, and to *then* discard Device to add those 3 dice and attempt to steal an item instead?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: With regular attacks, there is no "declaring intention" or "stack"... you simply do the normal attack and defense, and then if you would deal 2 or more damage, you can steal instead.

Comment: Since when does BAHOTH have anything remotely resembling a stack? You play cards, roll dice, play cards, move things, play cards, and roll dice in whatever order is necessary.

Comment: @Nij I think he was just using "stack" loosely to mean "the order that events happen in". As well as the MTG concept of "responding" to things... in this case, you can think of it like an MTG stack because you roll the dice, but before you resolve that die roll, you respond by activating Device. So there must be some period of time where the dice are rolled, but not resolved yet. In a way, that die roll is on the stack at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can discard Device after rolling.

You don't have to declare any sort of intention about your attack; stealing isn't something you "attempt" to do. When you attack, if you inflict 2 or more points of physical damage, then you can choose to steal an item instead of doing the damage. You don't have to declare before you roll whether you are trying to steal or not. Stealing is an option you have if you roll high enough.

Simply read literally, Device seems to imply that you can use it after rolling. It simply says "discard this card to add 3 to your attack roll". It doesn't give a restriction on when you can do that. So I make the attack roll, and then I can use Device if I want.

Although the wording on Device by itself does not make it completely clear if you need to discard it before or after rolling, we can look at other items to get an answer. Adrenaline Shot says "Before you attempt a trait roll you can use this item to add 4 to the result of that roll." So it specifies that it must be used before attempting the roll. It is a safe assumption that if Device intended you to have to use it before the tole, then it would have similar wording.